# Making fopen_s into fopen

Tags: c, fopen

I have this line of code here that is written in a way that I can't compile because according to Google, it's windows stuff and I have a Mac.
Can anyone please help me to change this line in a way that my Mac can read? I think I need to use fopen.

P.s: I am not good at C

```
errno_t err_in = fopen_s(&fp_in,   "audio.txt", "r");

errno_t err_out = fopen_s(&fp_out, "hpf.txt"  , "w");
```

Compile error:implicit declaration of function 'fopen_s' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]

Comment: `FILE *fp_in = fopen("audio.txt", "r"); if (fp_in == NULL) { perror("audio.txt"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }` and the same (give or take) for the other file. Remember to `fclose(fp_in);` when you're finished with the file.

Comment: BTW [`fopen_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) not "Windows stuff". It's C11 stuff.

Comment: @pmg thank you this was super helpful

Comment: @Jabberwocky It might officially be "C11 stuff", but [it's optional](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#K.2p1) and hasn't been implemented by a lot of implementations because it's [not really useful](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm#tc), the [design is fundamentally not thread-safe](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm#thrsafe), and the ubiquitous Microsoft ["implementation is incomplete and conforms neither to C11 nor to the original TR 24731-1"](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm#impementations)